# Typed NextJs link / route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

```
<Link href="/about">
     <a>About Us</a>
</Link>
```

Is there a way to enforce type safety for NextJs link?

At the moment, it is hard to refactor the Link. (As it is just a string)

I came across this repo, but the solution is not so elegant.
https://github.com/jagaapple/next-typed-routes

Is there something similar to Fluro from Flutter?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so I wrote [nextjs-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-routes) to solve it. It drops in to existing Nextjs projects without any application code changes.

*nextjs-routes* generates types for the pathname and query for every page in your pages directory. The generated types are written to `nextjs-routes.d.ts` which is automatically referenced by your Nextjs project's `tsconfig.json`. `nextjs-routes.d.ts` redefines the types for `next/link` and `next/router` and applies the generated route types.